# Problem of deploying all-in-one using Kolla tools

Tags: openstack, localhost, timeout, haproxy

Currently, I was building an Ubuntu OS for openstack"rocky" for testing.
I use kolla tools all-in-one instead of multinode.
I pass all of the prechecks and bootstrap-servers steps, but when I type

```
kolla-ansible -i ./multinode deploy
```

I got the error shown below.

In the last week I figured out that my error seems to be related to some haproxy setting, but I don't know why. When I went back to office today, the error log has changed:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
>   "attempts": 10,
>   "changed": false,
>   "elapsed": 60,
>   "msg": "Timeout when waiting for search string MariaDB in (MY ip address)

Does anyone know what this problem may be related to?